# AirBNB for Ukrainian eVisa or Passport Control

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas, borders, airbnb, proof-of-accommodation

Indian national working in Germany with a permanent resident permit here.

I plan to visit Kyiv and I am eligible for eVisa. One of the requirements for a tourist visa is:

> proof that the applicant’s main purpose of journey to Ukraine is
> tourism (hotel/accommodation booking(s), programme of stay,
> information on the tour(s) and the tour(s’) timeframes, tourist agency
> details, transfer details, sightseeing information etc.);

The wording here can be understood in so many ways. However, the internet seems divided about things like Couchsurfing or AirBNB, and whether hotels / hostels from something like Booking let's say acts as the only valid confirmation.

In many countries, people book stuff for the purpose of visa, only to cancel it later and be at the receiving end when they approach passport control. Especially, in countries like the UK or EU. My friend tried to do this when he wanted to visit me in Germany. Instead, I just gave him a letter of invitation which worked out pretty smoothly later.

In Russia, the officer at the consulate initially had no idea about AirBNB but eventually granted me the visa, same at the border control too, no questions asked.

Vloggers/bloggers, both foreigners and Indians, give suggestions like *"Please book a hotel, then cancel, and go for couchsurfing/AirBNB"*. Now, these guys live on a budget besides being with locals, so I understand this. This however may also demonstrate indirectly that they are lacking funds to cover their stay in hostels or hotels unless they have stellar bank statements to prove otherwise.

Although I do not plan to go this route, and I would rather just book an AirBNB if I feel confident, or just book a hostel / hotel and stick to it, what is the legality of travelers who do this, like book, cancel, and then live for free on-the-go? Especially when some countries may also have local registration laws even for short term tourists?

Hotels of course register you, but what about living with locals who are not your friends as such, but rather strangers?

I have no budget issues but I love to live in a local's residence, and I feel comfortable paying than living for free.

Nationals from India visiting Ukraine are given a tough time, understandably so because some what to get into illegal menial jobs or into the EU. Given that I have a weird combination of having a not-so-great passport but living in EU already for years, is AirBNB worth the shot?